# Swift Decoding Plist Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'd like to use a property list decoder to decode a binary plist of dictionaries

[image: Dictionary]

Object that makes dictionary:

```
struct ZipCode: Codable {

    var zipCode: String
    var city: String
    let state: String
    let latitude: String
    let longitude: String
    let timezone: String
    let daylightSavingsFlag: String
    let geopoint: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case zipCode = "Zip"
        case city = "City"
        case state = "State"
        case latitude = "Latitude"
        case longitude = "Longitude"
        case timezone = "Timezone"
        case daylightSavingsFlag = "Daylight savings time flag"
        case geopoint = "geopoint"
    }   
}
```

Wrapper object:

```
struct ZipCodeList: Codable {

    var zipCodes: [String:ZipCode]

}
```

Me trying to read it in which results in nil zipCodelist:

```
do {
           let path        = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ZipCodes", ofType: "plist")
           let binary         = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path!)
           let zipCodes = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(ZipCodeList.self, from: binary!)
           print("Hi")
    } catch {

}
```

Comment: Remove the ? from your `try?` so it throws an error and print it in the catch block

Comment: @dan I had done this earlier and gotten this keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "zipCodes", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"zipCodes\", intValue: nil) (\"zipCodes\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you that worked. You should Answer the question so you can get the reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plist doesn’t have an element zipCodes as a root element, instead decode as

```
let zipCodes = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([String: ZipCode].self, from: binary!)
```